# IBM MQManager as XA Transaction Manager with Spring-jms and Spring-tx

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms, distributed-transactions

We are trying to use IBM MQ manager as XA Transaction manager with spring-jms and spring transaction support. 
Does IBM MQ manager play well with spring-jta support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the WMQ JMS client (which is what spring-jms would use) with the MQ QueueManager acting as the XA transaction manager. The intention is that a JMS application would be controlled via a JTA implemented transaction manager (i.e. a Java EE application server).

You can however use the WMQ Java client (i.e. non JMS) and have the MQ QueueManager act as the XA transaction manager (non JTA).

As @COLINHY said you can use it the other way around. The Spring transaction manager will be the coordinator using JTA and the spring-jms can then be used to bring in the WMQ JMS client and MQ Queue Manager as a transactional resource.

Answer (score 3):

We used in the reverse way: Using Spring transaction management as the global transaction manager, MQ XA as one of the transaction branches. It worked fine.

Comment: Will be very useful, if you provide an example of your spring configuration entries for the queue connection factory and the queues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the support for MQ JMS client.

When installed within a JavaEE certified server, the MQ Resourced Adapter (powered by the JMS Client) will result in the MQ QueueManager working in a Resource Manager role, co-ordinated by the JavaEE Server.

Outside of the JavaEE environment the JMS Client is not supported when working with any other JTA provider. (if this of interest please raise a requirement)

With the MQ Java Classes (aka Base Java) - MQ can be a Transaction Manager but only with it co-ordinating itself MQ and a DB (such as Oracle and DB2).  It's not possible to get MQ to co-ordinate anything else.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. We have wrote Spring transaction manager implementation that now supports Base Java mq calls under the hood for managing transactions in binding mode.