# Standalone spring app XA transactions with IBM MQ and Oracle as resources

Tags: spring, oracle, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I am in the process of developing a stand alone Apache camel application (not running on a J2EE container).
This apps needs to be capable of routing messages from an IBM MQ queue manager to an Oracle database in a distributed transaction.
My google searches pretty much took me to a few places but none of those were able to give me some good clues about how to put everything together.
This link below was the closest to what I need but unfortunately it is not cler enough to put me on the right path.

[IBM MQManager as XA Transaction Manager with Spring-jms and Spring-tx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957045/ibm-mqmanager-as-xa-transaction-manager-with-spring-jms-and-spring-tx)

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Comment: It's also worth voting on this RFE; this is about adding support for additional JTA Transaction Co-ordinators (not just Atomikos)

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=36184

I would stress that the official support statement today says that only JavaEE certified servers can be used; this is because others such as Atomikos have not been validated when working with IBM MQ JMS.

Comment: @ Calanais the link u provided does not work.

Comment: Did you get to a IBM ID Sign in page? An id is required - this is free and quite simple to create.

Comment: Vote sent but as a personal opinion I doubt a monster like IBM will move on and implement this because four people in this world asked for it. It can be politics too not to implement it

Comment: Unfortunately the rfe @Calanais posted 5 years ago hasn't moved forward a bit.... According to ibm comment in 2013 ```Our intention is to provide formal support for any JTA-compliant implementation rather than specific named products. The timescale for this is undetermined.```, but not sure how good this _intention_ is today, since i haven't been able to find ANY instruction/best practice from ibm official dcumentation on how to incorporate v7 or higher jms client with JTA-compliant TM implementation.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a JTA TransactionManager, but since not being in a j2ee container i would sugest to use Atomikos.

https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction/tree/master/chapter9/xa

My route which is working with IBM MQ -> Oracle Database, in an J2EE yes but still should be working with Atomikos setup. I would say this isn't the proper way to to it, but it's the only way I managed to get it working - working well enough for my use case.

```
from(inQueue)
    .transacted()
    .setHeader("storeData", constant(false))
    .to("direct:a")
    .choice().when(header("storeData").isEqualTo(false)) // if this is true the database calls are 'successful'
    .log("Sending message to errorQueue")
    .to(errorQueue)
;

StoreDataBean storeDataBean = new StoreDataBean();
from("direct:a")
    .onException(Exception.class).handled(false).log("Rollbacking database changes").markRollbackOnlyLast().end()
    .transacted("PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW")
    .bean(storeDataBean) //storeData sets the header storeData to true if no SQLException or other exceptions are thrown
    .end()
;
```

The commit are handled by the transaction manager, so if I actually get an error with the database commit, it should rollback the message.
Next problem that I have had with rollbacking messages is that I can't set the deadLetterQueue, as you can with ActiveMQ. So it rolls back to the incoming queue. Therefore I actually handle the database transaction as I do, it is in a new transaction, which is rollbacked in case of a normal SQLException when calling the database.

I wished this worked:

```
from(inQueue)
    .onException(Exception.class).to(errorQueue).markRollbackOnly().end()
    .bean(storeDataBean)
    .end()
```

I have posted about this in the community forums but no answers at all.

Comment: Thank J2B for your comment. The example you pointed me to was exactly what I was following and I did managed to put Atomikos together and can see in the logs entries like this `##14-07-2015 08:43:42,112  [INFO ] atomikos - setRollbackOnly() called for transaction 10.16.164.34.tm0000600003
##14-07-2015 08:43:42,112  [WARN ] org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler - Transaction rollback (0x560513ce) redelivered(unknown)`. However my message is not rollbacked back to the queue I put it in and it is just gone instead (not good at all if u think it is a payment message :-)

Comment: I am using SJMS component which does not have a set transaction manager method. Should I switch to a JMS component or it is something I am still missing from my route configuration. Comparing with that "camel in action" example this is the bit I have not done yet `<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" depends-on="my-broker">
        <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
        <!-- refer to the transaction manager -->
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="jtaTransactionManager"/>
    </bean>`

Comment: OK so I got it working with JmsComponent. I tested by moving mesages between two MQ Webshere Queue Managers and the receiver one failing to accept the message as the destination queue was set to have "put inhibited." The transaction rollbacked to the source queue. I still need to see it working with database coming into picture as well but there is big confidence it will work. However I would still like to clarify how the SJMS component get set a transaction manager.

Comment: Since you are not working in an J2EE I would say it's even more easy to test this!

Anyhow, I myself had problems with getting this to work as I want to. See my edited anwer since there isn't enough characters when posting comments

Comment: @Julian if you find any better solution please share! :)