# IBM client with xa-transaction on Java EE

Tags: java, transactions, wildfly, ibm-mq, java-ee-8

I need to write producer and consumer for ibm mq with xa-transanction (write/read to mq and database in one transaction). My application based on Java EE and Wildfly 20. I know, that i can use ibm adapter wmq.jmsra.rar, but i need create and configure my JMS connection from application properties (because i have some applications in one server with different profiles). In IBM documentation writed, that i can use com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar for creating producer and consumer. It works, but there are not provided xa-transaction from the box on wildfly. Inside allclient.jar i find JmsXAConnectionFactory.java class, whitc provide XAResource (this class provide method commit, rollback and prepare, but there are need transaction Xid). How can i use xa-transaction in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr. Google gave the following links:

- [Running IBM MQ classes for Java applications within Java EE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031490_.html) scroll to the section that says: "***other application servers***"
- [IBM MQ resource adapter statement of support](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q128150_.html) scroll to the section that says: "***other application servers***"
- [Considerations when using IBM MQ and JMS with JEE Application Servers](https://www.mqtechconference.com/sessions_v2014/MQTC_2014-Using_WMQ_and_JavaEE_Together.pdf)
- [IBM MQ Manager as XA Transaction Manager with Spring-jms and Spring-tx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957045/ibm-mqmanager-as-xa-transaction-manager-with-spring-jms-and-spring-tx/)
- [Standalone spring app XA transactions with IBM MQ and Oracle as resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374595/standalone-spring-app-xa-transactions-with-ibm-mq-and-oracle-as-resources)